# Column name on NOT NULL constaint violation not shown

Tags: oracle, permissions, errors, oracle-19c

I'm using an Oracle 19 DB that is structured into multiple layers by using DB users. Here is a simplified overview of the structure:

- User DATA: Has the table `XTEST` and the view `TEST`. The view is created with a `CREATE VIEW TEST AS SELECT * FROM XTEST` statement, so it contains all columns of the table.
- User APP: Uses the view `DATA.TEST` for all SQL and DML.
  The APP user does not have any grants on the table `DATA.XTEST`, but does have SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE grants on the view `DATA.TEST`.

Now to my problem:
If a NOT NULL constraint on the table `DATA.XTEST` is violated, the error message doesn't show the column name. The error message is literally:

> ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into (???)

The DB used Oracle 11 some time ago and back then we had the same problem, but could fix it by granting the `REFERENCES` privilege on the table `DATA.XTEST` to the APP user (see related question: [Grant privilege to see column names in null constraint violations when inserting in views](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/102751/67452)). But this doesn't work any more in Oracle 19.

Does anyone know how to get the column name in the error message?

Comment: `grant select on data.xtest to app;`

Comment: @BalazsPapp The APP user must not have SELECT privileges on the actual table. The view might filter out some data that the app is not allowed to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the obvious solution (`grant select on data.xtest to app;`), you can revert to the old behavior by setting [SQL92_SECURITY](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/SQL92_SECURITY.html#GUID-E41087C2-250E-4201-908B-79E659B22A4B) to `FALSE`. In [11.2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/initparams244.htm), its default value was `FALSE`, but in [19c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/SQL92_SECURITY.html), its default value is `TRUE`.

```
alter system set sql92_security=false scope=spfile;
```

Then restart the database, as this parameter can not be changed online.

Demo:

```
create table bp.test (c1 number not null);
create view bp.xtest as select * from bp.test;
create user u1 identified by u1;
grant create session to u1;
grant select, insert, update, delete on bp.xtest to u1;
grant references on bp.test to u1;

SQL> show parameter sql92

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
sql92_security                       boolean     TRUE
SQL>

SQL> conn u1/u1
Connected.

SQL> insert into bp.xtest values(null);
insert into bp.xtest values(null)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into (???)
```

By changing the parameter:

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> alter system set sql92_security=false scope=spfile;

System altered.

SQL> startup force
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 2147481656 bytes
Fixed Size                  8898616 bytes
Variable Size             553648128 bytes
Database Buffers         1577058304 bytes
Redo Buffers                7876608 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> show parameter sql92

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
sql92_security                       boolean     FALSE
SQL> conn u1/u1
Connected.
SQL> insert into bp.xtest values(null);
insert into bp.xtest values(null)
                            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("BP"."TEST"."C1")
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a security consequence to setting SQL92_SECURITY to false.

From https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/oracle_database_12c/2020-04-01/finding/V-61429

> The configuration option SQL92_SECURITY specifies whether table-level
> SELECT privileges are required to execute an update or delete that
> references table column values. If this option is disabled (set to
> FALSE), the UPDATE privilege can be used to determine values that
> should require SELECT privileges. The SQL92_SECURITY setting of TRUE
> prevents the exploitation of user credentials with only DELETE or
> UPDATE privileges on a table from being able to derive column values
> in that table by performing a series of update/delete statements using
> a where clause, and rolling back the change.
>
> In the following example, with SQL92_SECURITY set to FALSE, a user
> with only delete privilege on the scott.emp table is able to derive
> that there is one employee with a salary greater than 3000. With
> SQL92_SECURITY set to TRUE, that user is prevented from attempting to
> derive a value.

SQL92_SECURITY = FALSE

```
SQL> delete from scott.emp where sal > 3000; 

1 row deleted 

SQL> rollback; 

Rollback complete
```

SQL92_SECURITY = TRUE

```
SQL> delete from scott.emp where sal > 3000; 

delete from scott.emp where sal > 3000 * 

ERROR at line 1: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

If this is a concern for you, then consider using a PL/SQL API package to make changes to your table, rather than granting access directly to the user. See "[Guarding Your Data Behind a Hard Shell PL/SQL API](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-1018211)" for reference. Also see here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=GZUgey3hwyI. A singleton package with definers rights could raise the error back to the app without granting excessive privileges or altering the overall security posture of your system.